# Howto add text legend on a stacked bar rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to update a stacked bar chart on the web (https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-D3.js/blob/master/Chapter07/Stacks/9-bar-na.html) because it is limited to three rows of data and I want to add some more rows.

Here is my full d3.js source :

```
<script>
    const width  = 600;
    const height = 400;
    const margin = 50;

    // some extra rows than the three original rows
    const populations = [
        {year: 1960, "Mexico": 38174, "Canada": 17917, "USA": 186808},
        {year: 1980, "Mexico": 69361, "Canada": 24537, "USA": 229763},
        {year: 2000, "Mexico": 101720, "Canada": 30736, "USA": 281983},
        {year: 2010, "Mexico": 110000, "Canada": 35000, "USA": 350000},
        {year: 2020, "Mexico": 130000, "Canada": 50000, "USA": 500000}
    ];
    
    console.log("populations : "+JSON.stringify(populations));
    
    const keys = ['USA', 'Mexico', 'Canada'];
    
    console.log("keys : "+keys);

    const stack = d3.stack()
            .keys(keys)
            .order(d3.stackOrderReverse);
    const stackedData = stack(populations);
    
    console.log("stackedData : "+JSON.stringify(stackedData));

    const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
            .domain([0,populations.length]);

    const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(d3.merge(stackedData)))])
            .range([margin,width - margin]);

    const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height",400)
            .attr("width",width);

    svg.selectAll(".year")
        .data(stackedData)
        .enter()
        .append("g").attr("class", "year")
        .style("fill", (d,i) => colorScale(i))      
        .each(function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .selectAll(".country")
                .data(d)
                .enter()
                .append("rect").attr("class", "country")
                    .attr('width', d => scale(d[1] - d[0]))
                    .attr('height', 20)
                    .attr('x', d => scale(d[0]))
                    .attr('y', (d,i) => i * 22)
        })
            .append("text")
            .text((d,i) => populations[i].year)
            .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("y", (d,i) => i * 22)
            .attr("x", 10);


    </script>
```

The problem is with the legends which are added at the wrong place.
D3.js adds the text inside every "g" markup and not after the first "g" only, after every "rect" markup as I wish.

I tried this :

```
coun=svg.select(".year").selectAll("rect").each(function(d,i) {
d3.select(this)
    .append("text")
    .text((d,i) => populations[i].year)
    .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("y", (d,i) => i * 22)
    .attr("x", 10)
});
```

But the text is added inside every rect markup.

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Jena-michel, France

Comment: could you please add sample sandbox, so we could give you solution there

Comment: I am sorry for the missing sandbox. I am not used to it but I'll do my best in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add labels independently in their own group:

```js
const width = 600;
const height = 400;
const margin = 50;

const populations = [
    {year: 1960, "Mexico": 38174, "Canada": 17917, "USA": 186808},
    {year: 1980, "Mexico": 69361, "Canada": 24537, "USA": 229763},
    {year: 2000, "Mexico": 101720, "Canada": 30736, "USA": 281983},
    {year: 2010, "Mexico": 110000, "Canada": 35000, "USA": 350000},
    {year: 2020, "Mexico": 130000, "Canada": 50000, "USA": 500000}
];


const keys = ['USA', 'Mexico', 'Canada'];

const stack = d3.stack()
.keys(keys)
.order(d3.stackOrderReverse);
const stackedData = stack(populations);

const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
.domain([0, populations.length]);

const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, d3.max(d3.merge(d3.merge(stackedData)))])
.range([margin, width - margin]);

const svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("height", 800)
.attr("width", width);

svg.selectAll(".year")
.data(stackedData)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "year")
.style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i))
.each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this)
        .selectAll(".country")
        .data(d)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "country")
        .attr('width', d => scale(d[1] - d[0]))
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('x', d => scale(d[0]))
        .attr('y', (d, i) => i * 22);
});
const yearLabels = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "yearLabels")
.attr("transform", "translate(0, -6)");

yearLabels.selectAll(".yearLabel")
.data(populations)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class", "yearLabel")
.text((d, i) => d.year)
.style("fill", "black")
.attr("y", (d, i) => (i + 1) * 22)
.attr("x", 0);

const legend = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "legend")
.attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${height - margin})`);

const legendItemHeight = 20;
const legendTextSize = 14;

legend.selectAll("rect")
.data(keys)
.enter()
.append("rect")
.attr("width", legendItemHeight)
.attr("height", legendItemHeight)
.attr("x", (d, i) => i * 100)
.style("fill", (d, i) => colorScale(i));

legend.selectAll("text")
.data(keys)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("y", legendItemHeight / 2 + legendTextSize / 2)
.attr("x", (d, i) => i * 100 + legendItemHeight + 5)
.text(d => d)
.style("font-size", `${legendTextSize}px`);

const totalBarHeight = stackedData[0].length * 22;

const legendY = totalBarHeight + 20;
legend.attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${legendY})`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.4/d3.min.js"></script>
```